# Can not draw multiple curves in a single graph based on conditons

Tags: laravel

I want to show multiple curves in a single graph of a webpage.
Like I want to show the values where value=4,these values will give a curve then in the same graph i want to draw the values where something's value=6..

How can I do this in Laravel??Can anyone give any tutorial of it or tell me the way??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this question is about Laravel framework. What you need is finding a free library/package to draw your graph. Then you can read it's document to see and learn how it works

Comment: @Vahid2015, sir to take the values from database, controller is using to get the datas.And blade file shows what controller sents the value.